# What's the most reasonable way when I want to LEFT JOIN two tables with ON conditions in JPQL without suffering from the N+1 problem?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Assume you have these two entities and corresponding tables (this is kind of a pseudo code; may not be really accurate Java code):

```java
@Entity
@Table("table_a")
public class A {
  @Id
  private int id;
  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private List<B> bList;
}

@Entity
@Table("table_b")
public class B {
  @Id
  private int id;
  @Column(name = "a_id")
  private int aId;
  @Column(name = "condition")
  private int condition;
}
```

What I want to achieve is (Pseudo JPQL):

```jpql
select a
from A a
left join B b on (
  a.id = b.aId
  and b.condition < 100
)
```

I'm using Hibernate 6.1.7.FINAL as a JPA implementation along with Spring Data JPA 3.0.8.

I tried several options:

1. Normal `JOIN` -> That must have the N+1 problem.
2. `JOIN FETCH` -> You cannot use `on` for join fetch for the JPQL syntax restriction.
3. Entity Graph -> I have originally used this way, but it was no longer working after upgrading Hibernate to 6.x according to https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15612.

Probably one possible option is `JOIN FETCH` and `WHERE` like

```jpql
select a
from A a
left fetch join B b
where
  (b.id is null) or (a.id = b.aId and b.condition < 100)
```

But actually you have to write `(b.id is null)` every time, and not semantically the same as the original one (maybe RDBMS can optimize it to some extend though).

Any other possible options?

---

Originally Hibernate 5 allowed me to use the following JPQL:

```jpql
select a
from A a
left join B b on (
  a.id = b.aId
  and b.condition < 100
)
```

with @EntityGraph (from Spring Data JPA), but now Hibernate 6 returns a SQL statement that contains duplicate `join` clauses (see HHH-15612 above).

Comment: did you try to write a sql query as a native with `nativeQuery = true` ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa Thank you Andrei, that's definitely another option. But I guess we may need to set a return type to `List<Object[]>` and convert it to POJOs by ourselves?

Comment: yes, but in hibernate 6 was changed this approach

Comment: Are you using TypedQuery or what exactly !!!, please share all your query statements, and what do you mean by N+1 problem ?

Comment: @AmineABBAOUI Basically I am using Hibernates via Spring Data JPA, which means `@Query(QUERY)` where QUERY is the JPQL statements I wrote in the question ([Reference](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query)). Regarding N+1 problem, for example [this blog article](https://vladmihalcea.com/n-plus-1-query-problem/) might be a good reference.

Comment: You cannot add filtering criteria to 'fetch' joins. JPA requires returned (aka managed) entities to reflect what is actually in the database - providers are required to track changes, so missing entities from relationships might show up depending on how that entity is merged back in and so force changes that weren't actually made back into the DB. If you want to control the query to fetch only some B instances, query on them directly, not the As.

Comment: @Chris Thank you Chris, my understanding is that such queries won't match JPA's philosophy. I wonder if we still should do that even when we want A itself as an array. It seems that I have to submit queries for `# of A records` x `# of B records` to RDBMS, which may be sometimes unacceptable for the performance reason.

Comment: fetch joins across many to many: there are other options. EclipseLink has a batchFetch option you can use on relationships, so 1 query for all As and 1 more query for all related Bs. I believe hibernate has similar options, I just don't know how well the batchSize annotation works. You can always query As and Bs yourself in a similar fashion, which of course by building As, would allow you to sort and filter the Bs in their B collections yourself too, and give you much more control for performance tuning